# Roslynator - how to disable C# 8.0 hints for .Net 4.7.2

Tags: visual-studio-2019, roslynator

I'm getting hints like "IDE0063  'using' statement can be simplified"

This is not a valid hint for a .Net 4.7.2 project. Why am I getting these?

===== Edit ======

[image: Language Version Selection]

Comment: Not a Roslynator message, the framework version is not relevant.  Ensure it is [not this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37475).

Comment: @HansPassant Hi, thanks for the comment. I don't seem to have <LangVersion> set on my Solution or Project and this still shows up.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hansPassant

You can create a Directory.Build.props file that contains the  element to configure multiple directories. You typically do that in your solution directory. Add the following to a Directory.Build.props file in your solution directory:

```
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You should delete your .vs folder as this will have cached information that will prevent this from working.